# Cannot rename eclipse project

Tags: eclipse

An Eclipse project can normally be renamed by a right click on the project folder and "Rename...". Every time I try this I get the message "Resource 'Project' is out of sync with file system". I get this message even if I do a refresh using F5. What could be the mistake here? Are there other ways than an export and import to rename the project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can export a project by clicking on

`FILE->EXPORT`.

then import this same project with

`FILE->IMPORT`

.
If you edit your files a lot outside Eclipse, enable auto-refresh with

`WINDOWS->PREFERENCES` then in the dialog box that appears, click on `GENERAL->WORKSPACE` and click `REFRESH AUTOMATICALLY`

Comment: Thank you for the hint with refresh automatically. Even if I do this, I get the error... damn!

Comment: That should have helped because thats what people are saying on the internet. Try exporting and importing the same project. Thats your best bet :)

Comment: I found the error while exporting the project ^^ I had a broken symlink within my project, now it works.

Answer (score 4):

You need to get your Eclipse project back in sync with the filesystem.

Just click on your project and press <kbd>F5</kbd> ("Sync with Filesystem") and then try again to rename it.

Comment: That's what I do and it does not work (see my edit)

Comment: Why the hell is "rename" not in the context menu while the project is open? I had to press F2 while the project was open, thinking it wasn't gonna work because the option shows up nowhere in the context menu, only to be surprised and finally have the damn thing let me rename the project. Broken UI.

Answer (score 2):

When you open an Eclipse workspace from within a clearcase view and try to rename the project, you will often get the pop-up warning ... “Resource ‘project’ is out of sync with the file system”.  If refreshing the project does not fix the problem, then do the following workaround:
a.  Open workspace WITHOUT being in a view
b.  Select the project in Project Explorer
c.  ClearCase -> Associate Project  (project should now look like project [] )
d.  Right click project -> Refresh  (vob sub-folders should now be empty)
e.  Right click project -> Rename ...
f.  Enter New name

Now you can close the workspace, reopen it in a view and refresh the project.  You may also dissociate the project if you prefer the project not to be associated with the vob.